# Problema com comparação de strings

Tags: java, string

Preciso comparar se o nome digitado no textField é igual ao usuário "root".
Na hora de comparar mesmo digitando root o Eclipse informa que é inválido.
Infelizmente não estou entendo o motivo do erro.

```
// ...
            model.Usuario mUser = new Usuario();

            // Enviar Usuario e Senha
            String tfUser = tfUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
            char[] tfPassword = tfSenha.getPassword();
            mUser.setUser(tfUser);
            mUser.setPassword(tfPassword);

            // ...
            if(tfUsuario.getText() == "root") {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Válido", "Aviso", 0);
                System.out.print(tfUsuario.getText());
            } else if(tfUsuario.getText() != "root") {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inválido", "Aviso", 0);
                System.out.print("Nome do Usuário: " + tfUsuario.getText());
            }
```

Comment: Isso é motivo para me pontuar negativo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o método `equals()` para comparar Strings em Java. Como a String em java é um objeto, quando você usa `==` compara o endereço de memória do objeto:

Ex:

```
if("texto1".equals("texto2")){

}
```

Comment: Allan, 
Muito obrigado meu nobre.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre deve-se usar o `equals()` quando se compara o valor de `Strings`.

Usar `==` traz confusões desse tipo:

```
String nome1 = new String("Marcela");
String nome2 = new String("Marcela");

System.out.println(nome1 == nome2); //false

String nome3 = "Marcela";
String nome4 = "Marcela";

System.out.println(nome3 == nome4); //true
```